# Как заэкранировать запрос к mysql? Не пропускает запрос со знаком тире

Tags: mysql

Есть код:

```
DBConnect();
$carBrand = $_GET['marka']; // в $carBrand лежит - alfa-romeo
$query = 'SELECT
            DISTINCT `model_eng`,
            `url_model`,
            `marka_eng`,
            `url_marka`
          FROM '.$carBrand.'
          WHERE `url_marka`="'.$carBrand.'";';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$onebrand = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

И в ответ получаю такой варнинг:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.ru\models.php on line 104

Если добавляю вывод ошибки mysql - `die(mysql_error());`, то получаю вот такую ошибку:

> SELECT DISTINCT `model_eng`,`url_model`,`marka_eng`,`url_marka` FROM
>   alfa-romeo WHERE `url_marka`="alfa-romeo"You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '-romeo WHERE
>   `url_marka`="alfa-romeo"' at line 1

То есть ругается на знак тире. А как ее заэкранировать-то? Я понимаю, что нужно использовать вот такие кавычки ``, но alfa-romeo находится в переменной. Никак не получается заэкранировать.

Comment: В обратные кавычки поставьте и название таблицы:

    ... FROM `'.$carBrand.'` WHERE ...

P.S. Вообще, на мой взгляд, не очень удачное решение использовать в названии таблиц тире/дефис/минус. Вы же не назовёте таблицу "a+b"? А в запросе мускул воспримит это именно как арифметическую операцию.

Comment: Пойду чуть дальше @Deonis и скажу, что это ненормализованная БД, и различные таблицы под марки и вовсе не нужны, потому что это всё может лежать в одной таблице с дополнительным столбцом 'brand'.

Answer (score 4):

*Ответ из комментариев*

В обратные кавычки поставьте и название таблицы, т.е. вместо

```
... FROM '.$carBrand.' WHERE ...
```

запишите

```
... FROM `'.$carBrand.'` WHERE ...
```

Вообще, не очень удачное решение использовать в названии таблиц тире/дефис/минус. Вы же не назовёте таблицу "a+b"? В запросе MySQL будет рассматривать это как арифметическую операцию.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте одинарные кавычки для вставки значений, таким образом у вас не будет проблем с дефисами и прочим

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`model_eng`, `a`.`url_model`, `a`.`marka_eng`, 
`a`.`url_marka` FROM `alfa-romeo` as `a` WHERE `a`.`url_marka`="alfa-romeo"
```

Вот так вот точно не будет